# i am trying to run this code as i am practising oop but i getting the error tuple object is not callable

Tags: python, tuples, python-3.7

I have made a method in the class which uses a tuple to retrieve two number 
   and find the average and print.
i have tried everything i can think of

```
class Footballer:
    def __init__(self,name,pace):#,physical,shot,passing):
        self.name=name
        self.pace=pace

    def pace(self):
        a,s=self.pace
        pace=int(a)*int(s)*0.5
        print(f" {name}'s pace is {pace}")

pace=(6,7)
leroy=Footballer('Leroy Sane',pace)
leroy.pace()
```

no error prints 6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the name `pace` as a method name, but then you try and use the same name for a data attribute (`self.pace=pace`) which overwrites your method. Try using different names.